# Fetch Unit consumption date-wise

Tags: mysql

I am struggling in to get result from mysql in the following way. I have 10 records in mysql db table having date and unit fields. I need to get used units on every date.

Table structure as follows, adding today unit with past previous unit in every record:

```
 Date        Units  
 ----------  ---------
 10/10/2012   101
 11/10/2012   111
 12/10/2012   121
 13/10/2012   140
 14/10/2012   150
 15/10/2012   155
 16/10/2012   170
 17/10/2012   180
 18/10/2012   185
 19/10/2012   200
```

Desired output will be :

```
 Date        Units  
 ----------  ---------
 10/10/2012   101
 11/10/2012   10
 12/10/2012   10
 13/10/2012   19
 14/10/2012   10
 15/10/2012   5
 16/10/2012   15
 17/10/2012   10
 18/10/2012   5
 19/10/2012   15
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is the relationship between units and units_used?

Comment: @7alhashmi: units_used is just alias for units in sql result.

Comment: I mean how you would get unit_used from the column Units?

Comment: I have just updated my question, so it will be clear now. I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to get the resultset. If you can live with an extra column in the resultset, and the order of the columns, then something like this is a workable approach.

---

**using user variables**

```
SELECT d.Date
     , IF(@prev_units IS NULL
         ,@diff := 0
         ,@diff := d.units - @prev_units
       ) AS `Units_used`
     , @prev_units := d.units AS `Units`
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_units := NULL ) i
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT t.Date, t.Units
           FROM mytable t
          ORDER BY t.Date, t.Units
       ) d
```

This returns the specified resultset, but it includes the Units column as well. It's possible to have that column filtered out, but it's more expensive, because of the way MySQL processes an inline view (MySQL calls it a "derived table")

To remove that extra column, you can wrap that in another query...

```
SELECT f.Date
     , f.Units_used
  FROM (
         query from above goes here
       ) f
 ORDER BY f.Date
```

but again, removing that column comes with the extra cost of materializing that result set a second time.

---

**using a semi-join**

If you are guaranteed to have a single row for each `Date` value, either stored as a DATE, or as a DATETIME with the timecomponent set to a constant, such as midnight, and no gaps in the Date value, and Date is defined as DATE or DATETIME datatype, then another query that will return the specifid result set:

```
SELECT t.Date
     , t.Units - s.Units AS Units_Used
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable s
    ON s.Date = t.Date + INTERVAL -1 DAY
  ORDER BY t.Date
```

If there's a missing Date value (a gap) such that there is no matching previous row, then Units_used will have a NULL value.

---

**using a correlated subquery**

If you don't have a guarantee of no "missing dates", but you have a guarantee that there is no more than one row for a particular Date, then another approach (usually more expensive in terms of performance) is to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.Date
     , ( t.Units - (SELECT s.Units 
                      FROM mytable s
                     WHERE s.Date < t.Date
                     ORDER BY s.Date DESC
                     LIMIT 1) 
       ) AS Units_used
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.Date, t.Units
```

Comment: Thanks your solution help me to achieve my desired result !!

Answer (score 1):

spencer7593's solution will be faster, but you can also do something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM rolling;
+----+-------+
| id | units |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   101 |
|  2 |   111 |
|  3 |   121 |
|  4 |   140 |
|  5 |   150 |
|  6 |   155 |
|  7 |   170 |
|  8 |   180 |
|  9 |   185 |
| 10 |   200 |
+----+-------+

SELECT a.id,COALESCE(a.units - b.units,a.units) units
  FROM 
 ( SELECT x.*
        , COUNT(*) rank
     FROM rolling x
 JOIN rolling y
       ON y.id <= x.id
GROUP
   BY x.id
 ) a     
LEFT
JOIN 
 ( SELECT x.*
        , COUNT(*) rank
     FROM rolling x
 JOIN rolling y
       ON y.id <= x.id
GROUP
   BY x.id
 ) b
ON b.rank= a.rank -1;

    +----+-------+
    | id | units |
    +----+-------+
    |  1 |   101 |
    |  2 |    10 |
    |  3 |    10 |
    |  4 |    19 |
    |  5 |    10 |
    |  6 |     5 |
    |  7 |    15 |
    |  8 |    10 |
    |  9 |     5 |
    | 10 |    15 |
    +----+-------+
```

Comment: +1. Very nice. This is also a workable approach; basically using a semijoin to get a count of preceding rows for each row (we could use the `Date` column in combination with the `id` column (if it exists) if we don't have a guarantee the `id` values are ascending in `Date` sequence.) With that count, we can essentially assign a "row sequence" to each row, and we can use that to join to the preceding row. Very nice. (The performance downside of this approach is with large sets, the size of the semijoin set can be huge, and the same resultset has to be materialized multiple times.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks - you correctly identified what was in fact a slight error in my query, that rendered it rather non-generic! To clarify: As long as values are unique, you can use the date column instead of the id column. All that matters is that the values are sequential. They do not need to be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired result. I don't know how your table is called so I named it "tbltest".
Naming a table date is generally a bad idea as it also refers to other things (functions, data types,...) so I renamed it "fdate". Using uppercase characters in field names or tablenames is also a bad idea as it makes your statements less database independent (some databases are case sensitive and some are not).

```
SELECT
  A.fdate,
  A.units - coalesce(B.units, 0) AS units
FROM
  tbltest A left join tbltest B ON A.fdate = B.fdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
A.units AS current_units,
IFNULL(A.units - LAG(A.units) OVER (ORDER BY A.id), A.units) AS difference
FROM
tbltest A;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).